# Is there some mental model or pattern I’m missing to adapt a type with various immutable forms which needs more complex fields?

Tags: rust

I’m trying to represent a type which can have various immutable forms (sounds like an enum) but needs more complex fields.

Each variant will have the same fields but will be differentiated by the values set.

The current implementation uses a different constructor to return an instance of a given type, however there’s no type information encoded in the struct itself.

I seem to find myself coming back to [this RFC](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/impl-trait-for-enum-variant/4131) with similar problems.

Is there some mental model or pattern I’m missing to adapt this in Rust?

```
pub struct TypeData {
    pub a_symbol: &'static str,
    pub b_symbol: &'static str,
    pub c_symbol: &'static str,
}

impl TypeData {
    pub fn type1() -> TypeData {
        TypeData  {
            // ...
        }
    }

    pub fn type2() -> TypeData {
        TypeData {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Each variant will have the same fields but will be differentiated by the values set.* — what stops you from just... doing that? `enum Foo { Type1 { pub a_symbol: &'static str, pub b_symbol: &'static str }, Type2 { pub a_symbol: &'static str, pub b_symbol: &'static str } }`?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I 'd like the literal values in the variant declarations. Each type will basically be a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to rely on composition:

```
pub struct TypeDataInner {
    pub a_symbol: &'static str,
    pub b_symbol: &'static str,
    pub c_symbol: &'static str,
}

pub enum TypeData {
    Type1(TypeDataInner),
    Type2(TypeDataInner),
}

impl TypeData {
    pub fn type1() -> TypeData {
        TypeData::Type1(TypeDataInner {
            // ...
        }
    }

    pub fn type2() -> TypeData {
        TypeData::Type2(TypeDataInner {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Another option is to use [`PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/marker/struct.PhantomData.html) which [will encode type information that gets erased after compilation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=367bf0d7c60d481cd0519e79095768f2):

```
pub struct TypeData<Type> {
    pub a_symbol: &'static str,
    pub b_symbol: &'static str,
    pub c_symbol: &'static str,
    _type: core::marker::PhantomData<Type>,
}

impl<T> TypeData<T> {
    pub fn type_t() -> TypeData<T> {
        TypeData {
            a_symbol: "",
            b_symbol: "",
            c_symbol: "",
            _type: core::marker::PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

struct Tr;

fn main() {
    TypeData::<Tr>::type_t();
}
```